# How to move from one tabBarController child view to another Tabbar controller in swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a `tabBarController` which have three tabs on Tab 3 i have a ViewController which have further child. But from that Child ViewController of `UITabBarController` index 3 i want to move at `UITabBarController` Index 1 how to do that kindly explain.

Comment: You can set the tabbar controller at index 1 as the root view controller.

Comment: from child view controller of index 3 how to move at index 1while child view has not tab bar controller

Answer (score 4):

Just set needed selectedindex for uitabbarviewcontroller.
Like

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: This solution works for my, if you dont need Observables or notifications